# Can't read integer file

Tags: java, file, txt

I'm trying to read data from a file that contains integers, but the Scanner doesn't read anything from that file.

I've tried to read the file from the `Scanner` :

```
// switch() blablabla 
case POPULATION:
            try {
                while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    this.listePops.add(sc.nextInt());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("~ERREUR~ : " + e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
```

And if I try to print each `sc.nextInt()` to the console, it just prints a blank line and then stops.
Now when I read the same file as a `String`:

```
?652432
531345
335975
164308
141220
1094283
328278
270582
// (Rest of the data)
```

So, I guess it can't read the file as a list of integers since there's a question mark at the beginning, but the problem is that this question mark doesn't appear anywhere in my file, so I can't remove it. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Is the last code block the console output or the file content?

Comment: It is the console output, the file content is the same except it doesn't have a question mark

Comment: you can't get rid of question mark at the beginning? and it only occurs once in the whole file? well that's clearly what's bothering sc.hasNextInt() since it's not int so it's false and breaks outta loop. If there's only once occurence of "?", maybe handle it seperately before you regularly start taking input.

Comment: What do you mean "the question mark doesn't appear anywhere in my file"? You see it when you print the file as a string. (Please add the code you are using to do that)

Comment: Read up on [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first character in the file is a question mark (**?**) and its original origin is unknown then it is usually the **UTF-8 [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)** (BOM). This means the file was saved as UTF-8. The Microsoft Notepad application will add a BOM to the saved text file if that file was saved in UTF-8 instead of ANSI. There are also other BOM characters for UTF-16, UTF-32, etc.

Reading a text file as String doesn't look like a bad idea now. Changing the save format of the file can work to but that BOM may have **actual** intended purpose for another application, so, that may not be a viable option. Let's read the file as String lines (read comments in code):

```
// Variable to hold the value of the UTF-8 BOM:
final String UTF8_BOM = "\uFEFF";

// List to hold the Integer numbers in file.
List<Integer> listePops = new ArrayList<>();
    
// 'Try With Resources' used to to auto-close file and free resources.
try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"))) {
    String line;
    int lineCount = 0;
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        line = reader.nextLine();
        line = line.trim();
        // Skip blank lines (if any):
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            continue; 
        }
        lineCount++;
        /* Is this the first line and is there a BOM at the 
           start of this line? If so, then remove it.    */
        if (lineCount == 1 && line.startsWith(UTF8_BOM)) {
            line = line.substring(1);
        }
            
        // Validate Line Data:
        // Is the line a String representation of an Integer Number?
        if (line.matches("\\d+")) {
            // Yes... then convert that line to Integer and add it to the List.
            listePops.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
        }
        // Move onto next file line...
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    // Do what you want with this exception (but don't ignore it):
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
    
// Display the gathered List contents:
for (Integer ints : listePops) {
    System.out.println(ints);
}
```